# Re-protect an Excel sheet, enabling Auto-Filters

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm using VB.net 2005 to input data from a database application into Excel files.

I un-protect the sheets, input data into specific cells using named ranges, then re-protect the sheets.

This has worked fine so far, up until I ran into a file that is protected with auto-filtering enabled. When I re-protect the sheets, I can't seem to protect it while allowing the use of autofilter dropdowns. The dropdown arrows for the autofilter are greyed out and disabled.

Using the following code to re-protect the sheets after inputting the data.

```
If bolProtected = True Then
   For i = 0 To intProtectIndexes.Length - 1
      objExcel.Sheets(intProtectIndexes(i)).Select()
      objExcel.ActiveSheet.Protect(strPassword)
   Next
End If
```

Also tried using the code from Tim's link.

```
objExcel.Sheets(intProtectIndexes(i)).Select()
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Protect(Password:=strPassword, Contents:=True)
objExcel.activesheet.enableautofilter = True
```

This still leaves the autofilter drop downs disabled on the populated worksheet.

Creating a macro in VBA and using:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect(Contents:=True, AllowFiltering:=True)
```

works fine. The sheet is protected and I can use the autofilter drop downs. But when I use that same code in my VB.net project, the drop downs are not enabled.

Comment: What do you mean with "can't seem to protect it while allowing the auto filtering option"? Maybe this helps you: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-autofilter-functionality-for-a-protected-worksheet-HA001098270.aspx

Comment: When I programmatically re-protect the sheets, any auto-filters that were in place before inserting the data are no longer usable. I think the link you gave has the answer. Make an answer, I'll test it and see if it works and give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
With objExcel.Sheets(intProtectIndexes(i))
    .Protect(Password:=strPassword, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True)
    .EnableAutoFilter = True
End With
```

Or

```
With objExcel.Sheets(intProtectIndexes(i))
    .Protect (Password:=strPassword, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True)
End With
```

Comment: The second option worked like a charm. Strange that it works with the Sheets() object, but not with ActiveSheet.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I would have though both options worked.  The first option definately requires UserInterfaceOnly:=True.

Comment: didn't even try the first option. I'd bet it would have worked also.